# how to get sum inside scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how to sum value inside Scope and store to another scope variable ?

```
$scope.cart = {
   { name: bag , price : 2000 },
   { name: shoes, price : 3000}
}
```

I want to store the total of sum into $scope.pay

how I can get there?

Comment: `$scope.cart` should be an array

Comment: @Syahrizal Setiawan If this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56930574/11572405 answer worked for you then kindly, accept this answer by clicking Tick and also Up Arrow button in front of my answer...Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Considering that `$scope.cart` should be an `array` you can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Code example:

```js
const $scope = {}
$scope.cart = [{name: 'bag', price: 2000}, {name: 'shoes', price: 3000}]
$scope.pay = $scope.cart.reduce((a, { price }) => price + a, 0)

console.log($scope.pay)
```

Comment: @Sammi yet another reason this question should be closed

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.cart = [
 { name: 'bag' , price : 2000 },
 { name: 'shoes', price : 3000}
];

$scope.pay = $scope.cart.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator.price + currentValue.price);
```

Cart needs to be an array. Use reduce function to get the sum. More info here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 0):

***Simple Solution to this is to use parseInt for adding two and storing it in new scope variable.***

**Angular JS File:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.sum = function (price1, price2) {
        $scope.pay = parseInt(price1) + parseInt(price2);
    }
});
```

**HTML File:**

```
<body>
    <div ng-app = "myApp" ng-controller = "myCtrl">
        Enter First Number:<input type = "text" ng-model = "price1" />
        <br />
        Enter Second Number:<input type = "text" ng-model = "price2" />
        <br />
        <input type = "button" value = "Add" ng-click = "sum(price1, price2)" />
        Total : pay <input type = "text" ng-model = "pay" />
    </div>
</body>
```

**Update 1:** BTW. $scope.cart should be array and to access every price, you should use ng-repeat.

```
$scope.cart = [
    {name:'bag', price : 2000},
    {name:'shoes', price : 3000}
    ];
```

Comment: @Syahrizal Setiawan If this answer worked for you then kindly, accept this answer by clicking Tick and also Up Arrow button in front of my answer...Thank you...